# Set brokerDurSubQueue property in Spring Boot+JMS+IBM MQ Durable Topic listener

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying to listen message through Spring boot application using IBM MQ topic subscription.

**Available info (Provided by MQ Admin):**

```
Topic name
Host
Port
QueueManager
BrokerDurableSubscriptionQueue
```

**I am trying to set BrokerDurableSubscriptionQueue property in MQConnectionFactory.**

I can find `mqConnectionFactory.setBrokerSubQueue(queueName)` which I guess can be used for Non-Durable Subscription.

**But I cannot find similar property for Durable subscription.**

However I can see **MQTopic** class  has **setBrokerDurSubQueue** property but I am not sure how can I make use of MQTopic object in my case.

I am using below code:

**MQConnectionFactory:**

```
@Bean

public MQTopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory(){

  MQTopicConnectionFactory mqTopicConnectionFactory= new MQConnectionFactory();

  mqTopicConnectionFactory.setHostName(); //mq host name

  mqTopicConnectionFactory.setPort(); // mq port

  mqTopicConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(); //mq queue manager

  mqTopicConnectionFactory.setChannel(); //mq channel name

  mqTopicConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);

  mqTopicConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(); //tls cipher suite name

  return mqTopicConnectionFactory;

}


@Bean

public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(MQTopicConnectionFactory  mqtopicConnectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer)
 {

DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();   

configurer.configure(factory, mqtopicConnectionFactory);

factory.setPubSubDomain(true);

factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);

return factory;

}
```

**Listener:**

```
@JmsListener(
destination = "someTopic",
subscription = "someTopic",
containerFactory = "topicListenerFactory" 
)

public void receiveMessage(String msg) {

repository.save(msg);

}
```

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for reply. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: I have cleaned up my comments and added all the details to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background:**

When you provide a specific queue for IBM MQ to use when you subscribe to a topic it is called a unmanaged subscription because MQ is not managing the underlying queue since you have provided it.

When a queue is not provided it is called a managed subscription, in this case MQ creates a queue for you to hold the published messages.

- If it is a non-durable subscription the queue created is a temporary dynamic queue with a name like:
  `SYSTEM.MANAGED.NDURABLE.<8 hex characters>`
- If it is a durable subscription the queue created is a permanent dynamic queue with a name like:
  `SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.<8 hex characters>`

---

What you have uncovered is that the IBM MQ classes for JMS API only supports managed subscriptions.

---

**Suggestions:**

I can suggest two options if you want to use IBM MQ classes for JMS API to receive messages published to a topic on a specific queue:

1. Have a MQ admin setup an administrative subscription on the queue manager.  You can do this a few different ways.  The example below would be using a MQSC command.

   `DEFINE SUB('XYZ') TOPICSTR('SOME/TOPIC') DEST(SOME.QUEUE)`
2. Create a utility app using IBM MQ classes for Java that can open a queue and create a durable subscription with a provided queue, the only purpose of this app would be to subscribe and unsubscribe a provided queue, it would not be used to consume any of the published messages.

For both options above you would have the IBM MQ classes for JMS API application open the queue to consume the published message, for all purposes it would not know or need to know the messages were published to a topic.  The message will still contain JMS headers showing the topic string where the message was published, so you can inquire this if required.  You could also subscribe multiple topics to a single queue if you like.